# Saving imageView with linear layout as image

Tags: android, performance, android-layout, android-intent, bitmap

I need to combine a imageView and a linear layout to save as image for share intent content. The Imageview is from list item ImageAdaptor. I am trying to create a dynamic layout and saving it as bitmap, then passing it to share intent.

[image]

The picture gives an idea for my requirement.

Below is my code for dynamic layout creation,

```
            LinearLayout sharelayout = new LinearLayout(context);
            ImageView tv1 = new ImageView(context);
            holder.image.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            holder.image.buildDrawingCache(true);
            tv1.setImageBitmap(holder.image.getDrawingCache());
            LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                    .getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

            LinearLayout bottom = (LinearLayout) vi.inflate(
                    R.layout.bottom_share, null);
            sharelayout.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
                    LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            sharelayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            sharelayout.addView(tv1);
            sharelayout.addView(bottom);

            sharelayout.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
            sharelayout
                    .setDrawingCacheQuality(View.DRAWING_CACHE_QUALITY_HIGH);
            sharelayout.buildDrawingCache(true);
            Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sharelayout
                    .getDrawingCache());

            Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
            shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
            shareIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
            // Add text and then Image URI
            // shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,
            // vals.getTime()+" "+vals.getPostUrl().toString()+"?utm_source=ws");
            shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,
                    getImageUri(context, bitmap));
            shareIntent.setType("image/jpeg");
            shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);

            try {
                context.startActivity(shareIntent);
            } catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex) {

            }
```

The code gives exception at Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(sharelayout.getDrawingCache());

I want to share Image with appended linear layout. Is there a better way to do achieve this ?

Comment: get bitmap from imageview is better, if imageview has bitmap.

Comment: The Image view has bitmap. need to append the linear layout and save resultant layout as bitmap

Comment: you can do screenshot of your layou using facebook-screenshot-library, you would fin on Github